# Find function and line number where variable gets modified

Tags: php

Let's say that at the beginning of a random function variable $variables['content'] is 1,000 characters long.

This random function is very long, with many nested functions within.

At the end of the function $variables['content'] is only 20 characters long.

How do you find which of nested functions modified this variable?

Comment: "How would you the line number inside that function"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. You want to know in which line that variable has changed (from `null` to something)?

Comment: You lost me at the last sentence/question.

Comment: maybe you can give an example, or some code :>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a problem code tracing can help with.

In my case I had this variable that was being modified across many functions, and I didn't know where.

The problem is that at some point in the program the variable (a string) was around 40,000 characters, then at the end of the program something had cut it to 20 characters.

To find this information I stepped through the code with the Zend debugger. I found the information I wanted (what functions modified the variable), but it took me a while.

Apparently XDebug does tell you what line numbers, in what functions the variables are modified:

[Example](http://derickrethans.nl/variable-tracing-with-xdebug.html), [tracing documentation](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace), [project home](http://xdebug.org/index.php), [tutorial article](http://devzone.zend.com/article/2803).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you'd want to return it but you could use the magic constant [`__LINE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php). That returns the line of the current document.

You could create a variable called `$variables['line']` and assign `__LINE__` as the value, where appropriate.

Comment: Sounds implementable, I'd try it. I guess I would still stick with a debugger since you don't have to touch one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, first I'd consider breaking apart the 1000-line beast. There's probably no good reason for it to be so huge. Yes, it'll take longer than just trying to monkey-patch your current bug, but you'll probably find dozens more bugs in that function just trying to break it apart.

Lecture over, I'd do a search/replace for `$variables['content'].*=([^;]*);` to a method call like this: `$variables['content'] = hello(\1, __LINE__);`. This will fail if you are assigning strings with semicolons in them or something similar, so make sure you inspect every change carefully. Write a `hello()` function that takes two parameters: whatever it is you're assigning to `$variables['content']` and the line number. In `hello()`, simply print your line number to the log or standard error or whatever is most convenient, and then return the first argument unchanged.

When you're done fixing it all up, you can either remove all those silly logging functions, or you can see if 'setting the `$variables['content']` action' is important enough to have its own function that does something useful. Refactoring can start small. :)